# Windows Universal Platform CalendarView change start day of week to Monday

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, calendarview

I have a CalendarView in my UWP app and I need to change the first day of the week from Sunday to Monday. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the [`CalendarView.FirstDayOfWeek`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/blob/docs/windows.ui.xaml.controls/calendarview_firstdayofweek.md) property.
Example:

```
MeCalendarView.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
```

Eventually in `XAML` :

```
<CalendarView FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"/>
```